# CalendarView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, calendarview

In my Android's Application I need to scroll Up and Down the months of a CalendarView placed inside a ScrollView and a LinearLayout.

This is my XML structure:

```
-ScrollView
--LinearLayout
---CalendarView
```

What should i do in order to let the calendar scroll Up and Down (hence select different month)?

Current ScrollView behavior seems to disable the calendar's scrolling.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you fnd any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tries using the CalendarView without the ScrollView? I'm able to scroll months simply in 
- ParentView (RelativeLayout in my case)
-- Other views
-- CalendarView

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom calendar View

scrollCalendar.java

```
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class scrollCalendar extends CalendarView {

public scrollCalendar(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public scrollCalendar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context,attrs);
}

public scrollCalendar(Context context,AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
}
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ViewParent p= this.getParent();
        if (p != null)
            p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

In Activity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <com.example.gateway.scrollCalendar
      android:id="@+id/calendarDate"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="250dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"
      android:visibility="gone">
  </com.example.gateway.scrollCalendar>

 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help for future users.Use below given custom scroll view class. in your xml just replace `ScrollView` with `nameofpackage.VerticalScrollView`. **nameofpackage** means full package name in which you put custom scroll view class.(i.e. if it is com.example than nameofpackage.VerticalScrollView = com.example.VerticalScrollView).

```
public class VerticalScrollView extends ScrollView{

    public VerticalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false" );
                return false;

            default: Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action ); break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction() );
        return true;
    }
}
```